# Crash In TapJoy Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, mobclix, tapjoy

When I had integrated TapJoy Interstitial ad it was working fine. But now, I have a mechanism that if Tapjoy fails to gives ad, I rollover to some other ad network like adMob, Mobclix, etc.
The problem is that the rolling over mechanism is working fine with all the ad networks, except Tapjoy.
In the case of Tapjoy, whenever it is getting failed and rollover is happening to admob, mobclix or Inmobi, the app is crashing.
Crash Logs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    at com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixFullScreenAdView$AdResponseHandler.<init>(MobclixFullScreenAdView.java:392)
    at com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixFullScreenAdView$AdResponseHandler.<init>(MobclixFullScreenAdView.java:392)
    at com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixFullScreenAdView.<init>(MobclixFullScreenAdView.java:104)
    at com.apostek.library.AdLibrary.loadInterstial(AdLibrary.java:1091)
    at com.apostek.library.AdLibrary.rollOverInterstial(AdLibrary.java:1450)
    at com.apostek.library.AdLibrary.access$0(AdLibrary.java:1447)
    at com.apostek.library.AdLibrary$9.getFeaturedAppResponseFailed(AdLibrary.java:1408)
    at com.tapjoy.TapjoyFeaturedApp$1.run(TapjoyFeaturedApp.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: Did my suggestion fix your problem?  It would be helpful to know whether or not this worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tapjoy `getFeaturedApp()` method is spawning a new thread and it sounds like your adMob library is expected to run on the main thread.  Try using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for your adMob code to run on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it looks like runOnUiThread should work. I'm on the move right now. Will try this ASAP

Comment: Thanks. It worked !!
I was out of town so couldn't check this earlier